# use abstract class inputverifier java in another class

Tags: java, extends, inputverifier

I have two classes

```
public class Finestra extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    ........
    jtextField.setinputVerifier(.....):
}

public abstract class Verifica extends InputVerifier{
    String message;
    public Verifica(String message){
    }

    public abstract boolean verifica(JtextField c);

    public boolean verify(Jcomponent c){
         JTextField c = (JTextField) jc;
    if (esito(c) == false){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
    }
}
```

I want to use Verifca class in finestra. I don't extends it because there is javax.swing.JFrame. Can i do to use Verifica? and is it a problem the only abstract method verifica.

I try this, but doesn' work

```
      testo.setInputVerifier(new Verifica("error") {
         public boolean verifica(testo){
             if (testo.getText == null){
                return true;
             }else{
                  return false;
             }

           }

      });
```

Comment: Can't you just have an instance of Verifica inside Finestra and pass it to setInputVerifier?

Comment: yes, but my dubt is abstract method verifica. How i can use it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to have an abstract class `Verifica` and then, when using it, to create an *anonymous class* with a custom implementation of the method `verifica`.

In the anonymous class definition that you're doing, you must override the variable with the same signature like this for example:

```
testo.setInputVerifier(new Verifica("error") {
     @Override
     public boolean verifica(JTextField c) {
         if (testo.getText == null){
            return true;
         } else{
              return false;
         }
     }

  });
```

You cannot "bind" your variable `testo` as the parameter for your `verifica` method in the anonymous class. You can, however, refer to `testo` directly from the outside scope of you anonymous class (so it gets bound in the implementation, not the signature of the method), resulting in something like this:

```
public abstract class Verifica extends InputVerifier {
    public abstract boolean verifica();
}
```

and

```
testo.setInputVerifier(new Verifica("error") {
     public boolean verifica() {
         if (testo.getText == null) {
            return true;
         } else {
              return false;
         }
       }
  });
```